# Is it better practice to do a 301 redirect in .htaccess or in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Simple question:

I'm trying to maintain a list of 301 redirects for SEO reasons and I want to know if its better to be using .htaccess with redirect rules or should I maintain the list of redirects in PHP.

If you could explain why either one is better that would be great!

Comment: Why the close votes? Seems like a good question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping your redirects in .htaccess will be better for performance, as there will be no PHP interpreter initialization required for each redirection. On the other hand, you can do additional processing if you do it in PHP (stats counting, etc). If you want simple redirects and nothing else, place them in .htaccess just for the performance advantage.

Answer (score 0):

For SEO purposes neither makes a difference as both results in the same thing; A Location change. Both are handled by the server and have the same impact on a Search Engine. So, based on that, go for whichever is the most efficient for you to handle.